# Query to Grouped Sums

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
Number      Amount
-------     -------
2014-07     3
2014-07     8
2014-07     9
2014-07     4
2014-07     5
2014-07     8
2014-07     18
2014-07     12
2014-01     12
2014-01     6
2014-01     9
2014-01     11
2014-01     12
2014-01     7
2014-01     9
2014-01     10
..............
..............
```

For `2014-07`: Add all amounts associated with 2014-07, which is (3+8+9+4+5+8+18+12) = 67.

For `2014-01`: Add all amounts associated with 2014-01, which is (12+6+9+11+12+7+9+10) = 76.

Note: use the same query to output other numbers in table like `2014-03`, `2014-02` and more.

I would like the query to output the following format:

```
2014-07     67
2014-01     76
```

Comment: isn't this the first query you learn? you should put some effort yourselves or you are not going to learn anytime.

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is correct, this query should give you the requested result:

```
select Number, sum(Amount) from Table group by Number
```

Comment: Actually: select Number, Sum(Amount) from table group by Number

Answer (score 0):

select Number, sum(Amount) from tablename group by Number

Here you are first selecting a number and correspondingly calculating the
Sum of all amounts corresponding to that number and printing it.
Now group by helps to output distinct number for the table.
The aggregate function sum is used to calculate the sum of all the amounts corresponding to a Number